# I have got two associative arrays of different lengths. I want to know how to compare values and apply to checkboxes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

There are two associative arrays of different lengths, how to compare their values and apply to checkboxes? If the values match, I need the checkbox gets the attribute checked.

**Now I have this:**

- Politics
- Video (Checked)
- Policy (Checked)
- Video

**I want**

- Video (Checked)
- Policy (Checked)

**My code at the monent:**

```
@foreach($category as $categories)
    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]"> {{$categories->title}}
    @foreach($post->category as $selected)
        @if($selected->title == $categories->title)
            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]" checked> {{$categories->title}}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You do have the result with you. No? Or do you want only checked boxes to show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply that condition inside element to apply checked property

```
@foreach($category as $categories)
    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]"> {{$categories->title}}
    @foreach($post->category as $selected)
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]" {{$selected->title == $categories->title ? 'checked' : ''}}> {{$categories->title}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem

**Controller:**

```
    $checkedCategory = [];

    foreach($post->category as $selected) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
            if($selected->title == $category[$i]->title) {
                $checkedCategory[$i] = $category[$i]->title;
            }
        }
    }

    $checkedCategory = array_values(array_unique($checkedCategory, SORT_REGULAR));
```

**Template:**

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Категории</legend>

            @foreach($category as $categories)
                @if(in_array($categories->title, $checkedCategory))
                    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]" checked> {{$categories->title}}
                @else
                    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="{{$categories->title}}" value="{{$categories->title}}" name="category[{{$categories->id}}]"> {{$categories->title}}
                @endif
            @endforeach

        </fieldset>
```